# Same disqus thread on http and https

Tags: github, jekyll, blogs, disqus

I have a jekyll blog with a disqus comment box hosted on github, but when someone comments over https those comments appear in a separate thread than the ones that comment over http.

Is there a way for both url to share the same disqus thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an explanation of how to avoid split threads:

https://help.disqus.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2158629

Basically, define the `url` and `identifier` configuration variables in your embed code so that the thread is related to a canonical URL instead of the window URL.

Here's the relevant part of the configuration:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = PAGE_URL; // The page's canonical URL
  this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // The page's unique identifier
}
```